# Cookies from $.ajax site to python3 server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, python-3.x

basically I looked everywhere for answers (google), I can't seem to find the solution. Basically what I'm doing is that I have a python server who scrapes sites and returns them to a page (depending on the url) in json. And the server gets the url's from a site where you enter where you want to search and what do you want to search. What I want to do is add cookies to the whole thing, because you can login to some sites for discount. What I can't figure out is how am i supposed to send my site cookies to my server. I'm using simplified code to test/find out how it works first.

Site URL:
http://localhost/looking/test.html

Server URL:
http://localhost:8082

Server request example:
http://localhost:8082/?search=dell&shop=rlyniceshop

HTML CODE

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-where="ASWO">Prisijungti</button>

    <script>
        if (Cookies.get('user') == null) {
            var user = Date.now();
            Cookies.set('user', user);
            console.log(Cookies.get('user'));
        }

        $('.btn-outline-success').on('click', function(){
            var url = 'http://localhost:8082/?search=dell&shop=pls';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "POST",
                cookie: "TestCookie2=AAA"
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

PYTHON CODE

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import urllib.request
import json
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
crm_path="PATH TO CHROME DRIVER"

class Object:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True)

class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.end_headers()
    parsed = urlparse(self.path)
    wow = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
    luk = ''.join(wow['search'])
    wer = ''.join(wow['parde'])
    print(luk+wer);
    message = "COMPLEX JSON"
    self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
    return

def run():
  print('starting server...')
  server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8082)
  httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
  print('running server...')
  httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

If you think I'm unclear on something, please ask.

Comment: Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so I figured it out on my own. It was easy to do as well tbh. Guess not sleeping well caught up with me. What i did was make a new **var**, where the **cookies** would be **stored** and send it **as data**. Like so:

```
var dat = Cookies.get()

$('.btn-outline-success').on('click', function(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:8082/?search=dell&parde=pls';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        data: dat
    });
});
```

And then get them from my site with **get_POST**, like so:

```
def do_POST(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost')
    self.end_headers()
    content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
    body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
    parsed_q = urlparse(self.path)
    parsed_b = urlparse(body.decode("utf-8"))
    search_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_q.query)
    user_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_b.path)
    #print(''.join(wow['search']));
    print(search_info);
    print(user_info);
    message = "Json code"
    self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
    return
```

This way i could keep my headers and send some additional data (**content_length**). I **kept** my **do_GET** **in python code**, just for the sake of **if i need it in the future**.

**My current code looks like this now:**

**PYTHON:**

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs
import urllib.request
import json
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
crm_path="C:\\Users\\Duma\\Desktop\\site\\BrowersDriver\\chromedriver.exe"

class Object:
    def toJSON(self):
        return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, sort_keys=True)

class testHTTPServer_RequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost')
        self.end_headers()
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        parsed_q = urlparse(self.path)
        parsed_b = urlparse(body.decode("utf-8"))
        search_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_q.query)
        user_info = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parsed_b.path)
        #print(''.join(wow['search']));
        print(search_info);
        print(user_info);
        message = "Json code"
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html; charset=utf-8')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.end_headers()
        message = "Nothing to see here."
        self.wfile.write(bytes(message, "utf8"))
        return

def run():
  print('starting server...')
  server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 8082)
  httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, testHTTPServer_RequestHandler)
  print('running server...')
  httpd.serve_forever()

run()
```

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-where="ASWO">Prisijungti</button>

        <script>
            if (Cookies.get('user') == null) {
                var user = Date.now();
                Cookies.set('user', user);
                console.log(Cookies.get('user'));
            }

            var dat = Cookies.get()

            $('.btn-outline-success').on('click', function(){
                var url = 'http://localhost:8082/?search=dell&parde=pls';
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    method: "POST",
                    data: dat
                });
            });


        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this will help someone in the future who is looking for something similar :)